# product of weakly convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f_\epsilon, g_\epsilon, f, f^*$ and $g$ be real-valued functions. Suppose that $f_\epsilon\left(x\right) \rightharpoonup f(x)$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ and $g_\epsilon(x) \rightharpoonup g(x)$ in $L^q(\Omega)$, where $1/p+1/q=1$. Suppose that $g_\epsilon\geq 0$ and $g\geq 0$, which are not equivalent to 0, and $f_\epsilon g_\epsilon \rightharpoonup f^*(x)g(x)$ in $L^1\left(\Omega\right)$. Can we conclude that $f=f^*$ a.e. when $g\not=0$?

Comment: If I'm not reading the question wrongly, then no: Let all the $g_\epsilon,g$ be $0$, and let $f_\epsilon=f=1$ and $f^*=0$. Then all of the convergences are trivially true, and $f_\epsilon g_\epsilon=0=f^*g$, but $f\neq f^*$.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal One of the functions should be positive. I will change the statement.

Comment: Xianjin  Please include your own thoughts on the question.  Do not turn to MSE to do your work and thinking and explanations for you.  You've earned enough rep that I shouldn't be having to remind you about what is expected of any asker on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $\Omega=(0,2\pi)$ and $f_n(x)=\sin(nx), g_n(x)=1+\sin(nx) \geq 0$. Then $f_n(x)$ converges weakly to $f(x)=0$, and $g_n(x)$ converges weakly to $g(x)=1$. Then 
$$f_n(x)g_n(x)=\sin(nx)(1+\sin(nx))=\sin(nx)+\sin^2(nx)=\sin(nx)+0.5-0.5\cos(2nx),$$
which converges to $f^*(x)=0.5$ weakly.

Comment: The convergence OP assumes is only weak convergence in $L^1$ and not strong convergence so this answer doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I am hoping I can work around that issue.

Comment: @RhysSteele Isn't it just the opposite? OP says $f_n\to f$ in $L^p,$ $g_n\to g$ in $L^q,$ and therefore $f_ng_n\to fg$ in $L^1$

Comment: @zhw note the use of $\rightharpoonup$ instead of $\to$ meaning weak convergence.

Comment: @RhysSteele  Oops, should have seen that, thank you.